# I found this old video on my computer and there's some sort of corruption? Please tell me what this is

Tags: avi, bug

The video format is .avi. It was recorded with an unregistered copy of Hypercam 1. I don't know exactly what kind of effect this is.
[Video](https://streamable.com/88pjs3)

Comment: Video appears to be unavailable.